# Emails bounced from Gmail only

Tags: email, dns, gmail

We've got a shared hosting account for the website and email of a small trail association.  About a week ago, people started complaining that their emails to us were being bounced with the message "DNS Error: 1421891 DNS type 'mx' lookup of [xxxx.org] responded with code SERVFAIL".  However, the  email system was working fine for everyone else.  It appears that only @gmail.com addresses are receiving this error, though I can't be entirely sure.

The hosting service insists that their server is running just fine, so the problem can't be on their end.  I've been pretty dissatisfied with this host, though, and I don't see any chatter on the internet about Gmail problems.  So what should I try next.

One other oddity:  when I run the site through http://www.isitdownrightnow.com, it tells me that the site is down, even though it seems to be running just fine.

Comment: can you share the real domain name?

Comment: montourtrail.org

Comment: Seems there are some issues with Hostgator DNS (server `VDC2-Cyrus1.win.hostgator.com`, which is involved in resolving your domain records, is not respondiing).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure that your MX record is resolving to correct IP address? Also, please check the SPF record settings at your end.

Make sure the firewall is not blocking the access for the emails to Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem magically fixed itself one day.  My feeling is that my hosting service fixed a problem and won't admit it.